# suspicious network activity from my laptop

Tags: networking

I was in this internet cafe and the moderator has told me that my laptop is scanning through all the IP's and MAC addresses connected to the LAN in some of form of an attack( sorry if this is a little ambiguous but that is what I could work out) , disconnecting internet in the entire network, he said that my IP is the source of the attack. Thinking through the things I've done with my laptop, I remembered that I used a friend's flash drive. Now could a malware disconnect an entire LAN's internet? Has any of you came across such a case? Is there any way I can make sure of that? and stopping it if true?

OS: Win7
Anti-malware: eset norton 8, up to date, scanning showed no malware

Comment: It's certainly within the realm of possibility for malware to disrupt an entire LAN to the point that no one's Internet works. What OS are you running? Is it fully patched? What anti-malware software package are you running? Are its malware definitions up to date? Did you run an anti-malware scan after learning of the problem?

Comment: @Spiff let me edit the question

Comment: I'm not a Windows guy, but isn't Norton a Symantec brand and Eset a competitor? "eset norton 8" doesn't make any sense to me.